# Area of Copper Needed to dissipate 24 W

Tags: heat, heatsink, power-dissipation

I need to know the area of 2oz copper needed to dissipate 24 W. The max temp is 100 C and the ambient temp is 40 C. Any equations I can use?

Comment: Use a [calculator](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2007/02/16/pcb-thermal-copper-area/)

Comment: Also you'd have to consider, airflow, are you an open box closed box, is it mounted so convection will help you?  It's not enough to just say yeah I put some copper down so it's fine.

Comment: This smells of homework (a bit). There's plenty of equation you can use, but one parameter you need to know/calculate/measure is the thermal resistance between the component and copper and between copper and air. Plus as SHG above notes there's plenty of other things you should take into account...

Comment: It's quite possible, if not likely, that you simply can't safely dissipate 24W this way. At some point even an infinite thin sheet of copper won't keep the temperature rise to less than the required amount because it's too thin.

Comment: @VladimirCravero can you post the equations that you do know? I cant find any that relate area to power. I can figure out the other components that are necessary. (its not homework..)

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy It will be in air

Comment: If it is one device wasting 24Watts you are in trouble .But if you had say 24 devices wasting 1 Watt each then it is easy .Remember that Spreading the heat is Key .

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you have a hope of getting there. [Here](http://www.iaasr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Using-PCB-copper-area-to-dissipate-the-heat-produced-by-surface-mount-components.-Rev1.pdf) is a good reference, I'll post the graph from the end of their exercise. Note that you are asking for 2.5°C/W (not sure if that's including thermal resistance from junction to board or not, but let's assume that it's case temperature you are specifying).

[image]

Note that increasing the area from 75mm x 75mm to 100mm x 100mm (77% increase in area) only slightly decreases the thermal resistance, from about 50°C/W to maybe 40°C/W.

It's not simple linear equations to calculate this kind of thing- finite element modelling or building a mockup is going to give the best results, but I think we can conclude that anything much better than about 20-25°C/W is unlikely.

Here's what a [suitable commercial heat sink](http://www.wakefield-vette.com/Portals/0/resources/datasheets/641.pdf) looks like. It's about 3" x 4.125" x 1" (76mm x 95mm x 25.4mm) and the aluminum is 4.7mm thick at the base.

[image]

Comment: +1. Alternatively, if he can distribute the heat - perhaps 24 separate 1W sources each with its own copper area - that might work.